# Automatic generation of Fortran 2003 bindings from C library headers (using iso_c_bindings intrinsic module)

Tags: c, binding, fortran, fortran2003, fortran-iso-c-binding

Is there a tool to *automatically* generate Fortan **bindings** from C library header, using intrinsic `iso_c_bindings` module from Fortran 2003 standard?

I am not interested in ***translating*** C to Fortran, but only generating bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An automatic tool was used to get the [gtk-fortran](https://github.com/jerryd/gtk-fortran) bindings. It is a Python script [`cfwrapper.py`](https://github.com/jerryd/gtk-fortran/blob/master/src/cfwrapper.py). You might be able to adapt it to for your needs, although for my small problems I finally chose to make the bindings by hand.

Comment: Could you please provide link to `cfwrapper.py` script?

Answer (score 1):

Another project to consider is h2m: https://github.com/dan-nagle/h2m

However, at this time, on macOS, I cannot successfully compile h2m.